# Non Salesforce Users' Lotus Notes emails recorded in Salesforce

Tags: email

I have edited my question to make it more clear

====

I have a requirement where Non Salesforce Users want to record/track their Lotus Notes emails into Salesforce. BUT, they want to record in such a way that the email is recorded appropriately to contact/opportunity in Salesforce.

Example : The user (Non Salesforce) gets some appreciation note as a Lotus Notes email from manager/VP about a certain product. He wants to record it for a particular contact in Salesforce, is there a way to do it? Likewise, there are certain ongoing "projects" (again in Lotus Notes email) going on which they want to record as opportunity in Salesforce.

Please let me know if this is feasible out of box / any app exchange products available? If not, if someone can please advise on the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if i am wrong...If it is about keeping Tracking of email in Salesforce which users sent, then **InboundEmail handler** can be [used](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_To_Email_Services_on_Force.com)...With custom logic emails can be tracked and stored in a custom object.

Inbound email handler will spit out a weird email address, workaround for that would be use a dedicated email address ( share it with users ), from that email address bounce it to Salesforce generated email address. In case if there is any attachments along with the mail it can be stored as Attachment along with the mail

Comment: I have edited my questions to make it more clear. Please review the question again and let me know if you have any inputs.

Comment: Even for this situation you can use InBoundEmail Handler...For attaching mail to specific product, need to come up with custom solution like putting Product Id in the subject and parsing the subject and searching for the product id and tagging that mail into that product

Comment: this sounds reasonable to me. As @ForceDeveloper has said in their comment, you might have to do some jiggery-pokery to attach the e-mail to a specific record using a Trigger on sObject EmailMessage (I think?) and getting the "sender" to put the contact name/number in the subject or something (why not standard support [ref:xxx] style)